# Javascript Image not rendered unless global

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to render an image from a sprite sheet using JS. The curious thing is, unless the object that does the rendering is global, it doesn't work (see code and comments). The behaviour is identical in both FF and Chrome.

`resetGame()` is executed on page load.

```
var TILE_SIZE = 24;

function CharacterImage(imageSource)
{
    var tile_x = 0;
    var tile_y = 0;

    var img = new Image();
    img.src = imageSource;

    this.render = function(ctx, x, y)
    {
        ctx.drawImage(img, tile_x, tile_y, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, 
                x * TILE_SIZE, y * TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE);
    }
}

function Hero(canvas, image)
{
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var img = image;

    this.render = function()
    {
        var x = 1;
        var y = 1;
        img.render(ctx, x, y);
    }
}

// If the heroImage is constructed here, instead of within the function below,
// the image is rendered as expected.
var heroImage = new CharacterImage("img/sf2-characters.png");

function resetGame()
{
    var heroCanvas = document.getElementById("heroLayer");

    // On the otherhand, if the object is constructed here, instead of
    // globally, the rendering doesn't work.
    var heroImage = new CharacterImage("img/sf2-characters.png");
    var hero = new Hero(heroCanvas, heroImage);
    hero.render();
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling `resetGame()`?

Comment: on page load, like he said in the question

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? Do you get an error message, nothing happens, what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh hang on I think I see what's happening. The image needs time to load, so you should somehow bind an event to the loading of the image. This could be done as for example:

```
var TILE_SIZE = 24;

function CharacterImage(imageSource)
{
    var tile_x = 0;
    var tile_y = 0;

    var img = new Image();
    img.src = imageSource;

    this.render = function(ctx, x, y)
    {
        ctx.drawImage(img, tile_x, tile_y, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, 
                x * TILE_SIZE, y * TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE);
    }
    // Set up a "load" event for the img
    this.loaded = function(callback) {
        img.addEventListener('load', callback);
    }
}

function resetGame()
{
    var heroCanvas = document.getElementById("heroLayer");

    var heroImage = new CharacterImage("img/sf2-characters.png");
    var hero;
    // Initiate the "load" event
    heroImage.loaded(function() {
        hero = new Hero(heroCanvas, heroImage);
        hero.render();
    };
}
```

What you'll probably want though is some sort of preloader "class"/event that keeps track of everything being loaded before you actually continue with rendering. It could look something like this.

```js
var TILE_SIZE=60;

function Sprite(imageSource)
{
    this.img = new Image();
    this.img.src = imageSource;
    this.position = { x:0, y:0 };
}
Sprite.prototype = {
    isLoaded: function() { 
        return this.img.complete; 
    },
    onLoad: function(callback) {
        if (typeof callback !== "function") return;
        if (this.isLoaded()) {
             callback();
        }
        else {
            this.img.removeEventListener('load', callback);
            this.img.addEventListener('load', callback);
        }
    },
    moveBy: function(x, y) {
        this.position.x += x;
        this.position.y += y;
    },
    render: function(ctx) {
        if (!this.isLoaded()) return;
        ctx.drawImage(this.img, this.position.x * TILE_SIZE, this.position.y * TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE);
    }
};

function SpriteList()
{
    this.list = {};
}
SpriteList.prototype = {
    isLoaded: function() {
        for (var i in this.list) {
            if (!this.list[i].isLoaded()) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    },
    _onLoadFunc: null,
    onLoad: function(callback) {
        this._onLoadFunc = callback;
        this.onImageLoaded();
    },
    onImageLoaded: function() {
        if (this.isLoaded() && typeof this._onLoadFunc === "function") {
            this._onLoadFunc();
        } 
    },
    add: function(name, sprite) {
        this.list[name] = sprite;
        sprite.onLoad(this.onImageLoaded.bind(this));
    },
    get: function(name) {
        return this.list[name];
    }
};

var sprites = new SpriteList();

sprites.add("player", new Sprite("http://www.fillmurray.com/200/200"));
sprites.add("enemy", new Sprite("http://www.fillmurray.com/100/100"));
sprites.add("pickup", new Sprite("http://www.fillmurray.com/60/60"));

sprites.get("pickup").moveBy(1,2);
sprites.get("enemy").moveBy(2,0);

sprites.onLoad(function() {
    document.getElementById("loading").innerHTML = "Loaded!";
    var c = document.getElementById("ctx");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    sprites.get("player").render(ctx);
    sprites.get("enemy").render(ctx);
    sprites.get("pickup").render(ctx);
});
```

```html
<div id="loading">Loading...</div>
<canvas id="ctx" width="200" height="200">
```

Anyways, that's why your code isn't firing, probably.

Comment: Thanks. This looks promising. I'm working on another part of the game so once I get a chance to try out your suggestion, I'll select this as the answer if it works out.